# What's the benefit of using enum embedded inside a class in JAVA?

Tags: java, enums

What's the benefit of using `enum` embedded inside a class in JAVA? Like so:

```
public class Outter {
    public enum Color {
        WHITE, BLACK, RED, YELLOW, BLUE
    }
}
```

Comment: You would embed an enum in a class for the same reasons you would embed a class in a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The advantage of using an `enum` is that it is the clearest and most type-safe way of expressing the programmer's intent.  In this case ... it is declaring a set of 5 named "colour" values in a way that prevents them from being confused with any other values in your Java program.

The advantage of embedding the `enum` cannot be discerned from this highly artificial example, but it is typically that the embedded class / enum has a close semantic relationship to the enclosing class.

Answer (score 1):

To say this: The existence of colors WHITE, BLACK, RED, YELLOW, BLUE is limited to Outer. Such colors do not exist or have no meaning elsewhere.

For example, the body parts BRAIN, EYES, NOSE don't apply to trees, vehicles and so on but only to animals.

Answer (score 0):

it just stores the elements like array stores the elements in it and for the enum there will be an auto incrementation of numbers

Answer (score 0):

extending Stephen C's answer:

consider you code with slight modification.

```
public class Outter {
    public enum Color {
        WHITE, BLACK, RED, YELLOW, BLUE
    }

    void setColor(Outter.Color color){
        //The Outter's colors can only be WHITE, BLACK, RED, YELLOW OR BLUE
    }
}
```

Outter.Color can still be used elsewhere, but now Outter can only use its own Color.
See it all depends on how you use it. (it could be of no use for outter  if there doesn't exist setColor)

Comment: Do you mean Otter?   :-)